# Будет ли сумма чисел натуральной если они типа int?

Tags: математика

Пусть `х`, `y` и `z` числа типа int, и `х`, `y` натуральные. `z = x + y`. Для каких `x` и `y` число `z` будет натуральным?

Comment: Это зависит от их разрядности. Если z будет больше вместимости int, вы получите отрицательное (ненатуральное) число. Если использовать uint, то не получите

Comment: в языке програмирования -Python - ответ "да"

Comment: Вопрос с подвохом, конечно. Без привязки к конкретному обработчику окончательный ответ дать тяжело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer` является 32 битным (или 31 разрядным) целым числом, которое содержит в себе отрицательные значения. Натуральными считаются значения больше 0, которые выведены посредством натурального счёта. Максимальное значение `Integer = 2 147 483 647`. Языки по разному обрабатывают событие, когда значение переменной данного типа превышает порог.

`x` должен в таком случае принадлежать любому натуральному значению от 0 до 2 147 483 647

`y` зависит от `x` как: `2 147 483 647 - x`, в результате этого выражения получается максимум для нашего типа `Int`, нужно чтобы `y` был меньше или равен этой разности

Как итог, `x+y = Z`, где `Z` всегда будет натуральным при данных правилах

---

Перефразировать можно следующим образом

у нас есть

```
x ∈ N;
y ∈ N;
```

Мы хотим

```
Z ∈ N;
```

Если у типа есть `MAX_VALUE`, можно понять что, в результате суммы `x+y=Z`, число `Z` будет натуральным из следующих условий:

```
0=>X<=MAX_VALUE
Y<=MAX_VALUE-X
```

Comment: Противоречите сами себе. "Языки по разному обрабатывают событие" - в том числе могут сделать число ненатуральным

Comment: @andreymal могут, но, в теории, по правилам выше, оно всегда будет оставаться натуральным int, всё остальное - детали конкретного языка в контексте. Нам дали конкретно понять, что мы работаем с int и желаем видеть int, да так, чтобы он был натурален, в противных случаях будут происходить различные события, которые в контексте будут по разному обрабатываться, в зависимости от многих факторов

Comment: @andreymal Таких факторов как: язык программирования, компилятор/интерпретатор, фаза луны и перешла ли сегодня чёрная кошка дорогу. Конечно, есть два популярных случая, когда значение становиться ненатуральным, при несоблюдении правил в ответе, а так же изменение типа переменной

Comment: 31 разрядным, если быть точным.

Comment: @andreymal Давайте так: кто сможет назвать язык, где не произойдёт переполнение и будет можно получить отрицательное число?

Comment: @rotabor Java например, вот сурс -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504182/17393350 и еще один -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397510/17393350

Comment: @rotabor а зачем вы объединили два противоречащих друг другу требования? Отрицательное число получается именно из-за переполнения

Comment: Не знаю, не знаю. При переполнении в ЯВУ должно сработать исключение и результат не будет вычислен.

Comment: Это - уже ответ.

Comment: Про переполнение: в задаче мы не привязаны к языку программирования, следовательно, скорее всего переполнения, как готового объясненного объекта в нашей задаче нет. Как писал выше(преподаватель дал подсказку), числа рассматриваются в виде множества вычетов по какому то модулю. А что вот с этой информацией делать я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Идут баталии по поводу того, всегда ли получим переполнение или число сможет уйти в минус.

При переполнении может вызываться исключение (похоже, что это очень редкая вещь), что приводит к прерываению выполнения программы и результат операции **неизвестен**. Если исключения нет, тогда получим отрицательное число, или какой-то другой результат в зависимости от используемого языка программирования. В C#, например, получается отрицательное число.

```
using System;
class TestArithmeticOverflow {
    static void Main() {
        int a = 2147483647, b = 2147483647, c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine(c); // -2
    }
}
```

Всё дело здесь в том, что целые машинные типы могут интерпретироваться как числа со знаком или как числа без знака. Для минимизации знаков в тексте возьмём байт: это могут быть числа от -128 до 127 или от 0 до 255. В двоичном представлении -1 и 255 будут выглядеть одинаково 11111111. Процессоры устроены так, что они позволяют сложить 64 и 64 и получить 128, но при этом выставляется признак переполнения и признак отрицательного числа (128 = -128 = 10000000).

**P. S.**

Если исходить из такой постановки задачи "Проблема в том что я не привязан задачей к конкретному языку. Все что сказал преподаватель это то что числа рассматриваются не как числа в этой задаче, а как множество вычетов по модую", то правильным ответом будет являться вторая чать ответа *Acinit*. Если условия для x и y соблюдаться не будут, то не будет соблюдаться равенство "z = x + y".

Comment: Спорное утверждение "При переполнении вызывается исключение" - в C и C++ переполнение - неопределённое поведение (не исключение), в Java - переполнение приводит к результату по модулю (тоже не исключение), в Ruby и Python - переполнения не бывает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "При переполнении вызывается исключение" - это часть утверждения. Вторая его часть - это "Если исключения нет, тогда получим отрицательное число". "Ну и в ЯВУ могут быть свои заморочки на счёт этого" - а  это про C, C++, Java, Ruby & Python.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но ваш комментарий хорошо дополняет ответ, и я против изложенного в нём не возражаю.

Comment: Проблема в том что я не привязан задачей к конкретному языку. Все что сказал преподаватель это то что числа рассматриваются не как числа в этой задаче, а как множество вычетов по модую